TYPO3 12 force language for CONTENT object
TYPO3 12, PHP 8.2.
I want to force the language of a certain CONTENT object so it does work for all languages and must not be translated. Since its content is not language dependend this should save the editor work. Unfortunately this does not work. I have not found any documentation on how to force the language for CONTENT, HMENU or anything else... The following is a simplified version of what i am trying to do but should bring the point across...
lib.socialMediaMenu = CONTENT
lib.socialMediaMenu {
    table = pages
    select {
        pidInList ={$settings.nav.social} 
        where = sys_language_uid = 0
        orderBy = sorting
    }

    # Wrap each link item
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10 {
            field = title
            typolink {
                parameter.field = uid
                additionalParams = &L=0  # no sure if required
                ATagParams = class="social-link"
            }
            wrap = <li>|</li>
        }
    }
    wrap = <ul class="social-media-menu">|</ul>
}



the TypoScript only influences the Frontend rendering. so it has no influence on the Backend User Expericence.
while its possilbe to query content from a different Language, in your case where = sys_language_uid = 0 it will not prevent the editor from "translating" the elements and in this case they might be confused why the translated changes do not show up.
this line below forces the links to point to language 0, so it will change the language the user is browsing the site in. my guess this is not what you want even if your re-use the default language content
additionalParams = &L=0  # no sure if required
in general TYPO3 has options like Language Fallbacks to handle translations depending on your configuration "non translated" content might show up if there is no translation.
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AddLanguages.html#confval-sitehandling-addinglanguages-fallbacktype
I am not sure there a "easy" way to prevent translation of certain content.

i think there is a misunderstanding. i dont care about the backend. i just want to force the frontend link generation to use the base language, no matter what languages exist in the backend
